# Dynamic population of angular permissions

Tags: angularjs, angular-permission

This is my html code

```
<li ng-class="{active: collapseVar == menu.Id}" ng-repeat="menu in side_menu"
                  permission-only="{{menu.permission}}" permission>
    <a style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#00BCD4" ng-click="check(menu.Id)">
        <i class="fa {{menu.icon}} fa-2x" style="margin-right:5px;"></i>{{menu.name}} 
        <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level" collapse="collapseVar!=menu.Id">
        <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-repeat="sub_menu in menu.sub_views">
            <a style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#59C8D7" ui-sref="{{sub_menu.state}}">
               {{sub_menu.name}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I need to populate permissions dynamically
But i am getting this error

> angular.js:14525 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{'
>   invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{menu.permission}}]
>   starting at [{menu.permission}}].
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bmenu.permission%7D%7D&p4=%7Bmenu.permission%7D%7D
>   at angular.js:66 at AST.throwError (angular.js:15090) at AST.object
>   (angular.js:15079) at AST.primary (angular.js:14968) at AST.unary
>   (angular.js:14956) at AST.multiplicative (angular.js:14943) at
>   AST.additive (angular.js:14934) at AST.relational (angular.js:14925)
>   at AST.equality (angular.js:14916) at AST.logicalAND
>   (angular.js:14908)

Comment: What is` permission-only="{{menu.permission}}" permission` please post link to this plugin

Comment: This is the plugin [link](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission)

Answer (score 0):

please try passing without using parentheses {{}}

```
<li ng-class="{active: collapseVar == menu.Id}" ng-repeat="menu in side_menu"
                  permission-only="menu.permission" permission>
```

case permission-only accept argument ( `only: '=?permissionOnly'`) from documentation.
https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission/blob/master/src/permission/directives/permission.js

Comment: It treats it like a string.

Comment: can you please , make function and return menu.permission and call function and see , what should happen 
or menu undefined.


down vote
please try passing without using parentheses {{}}

<li ng-class="{active: collapseVar == menu.Id}" ng-repeat="menu in side_menu"
                  permission-only=youFunction()" permission>